# Can I use "GZSDF" to convert an URDF file into a SDF file?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I use "GZSDF" to convert an URDF file into a SDF file???

-I have my urdf(01-myfirstyo.urdf) in the next path:

/home/john/ros/01-myfirstyo.urdf

- I tried several methods to convert an urdf file into a sdf file (with gzdf in ROS FUERTE) and they didnt work:

FIRST TRY:

john@john-K53SD:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo$ source setup.bash

john@john-K53SD:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo$ ./gazebo/bin/gzsdf print /home/john/ros/01-myfirstyo.urdf

Warning [parser.cc:348] Gazebo SDF has no gazebo element

Error [parser.cc:263] parse as old deprecated model file failed.

Error: SDF parsing the xml failed

SECOND TRY:

john@john-K53SD:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo$ source setup.bash

john@john-K53SD:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo$ ./gazebo/bin/gzsdf convert /home/john/ros/01-myfirstyo.urdf

Error: Unknown option[convert]
This tool provides information about SDF files.

gzsdf  [file]

Commands:

```
describe   Print the SDF format.

check      Check the SDF format for the given file.

print      Prints SDF, useful for debugging parser and as a conversion tool.
```

Please tell me what am i doing wrong???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53994/can-i-use-%22gzsdf%22-to-convert-an-urdf-file-into-a-sdf-file???/) by [Jey_316](https://answers.ros.org/users/3661/jey_316/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-02-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I had a similar error in fuerte. After I had installed the groovy I have completed the conversion without error by command:

```
gzsdf print *.urdf
```

Alex

---

Originally posted by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) with karma: 641 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) on 2013-02-18**:
Was you conversion in fact correct? In my case it only properly converted visual properties.

**Comment by [Alexandr Buyval](https://answers.ros.org/users/691/alexandr-buyval/) on 2013-02-19**:
Conversion was correct after I had deleted all xacro properties like "${M_PI/2}"